# How to attach click to header child without reusing the code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I optimize my jQuery?  I remove the extra code to attach click event to the header tags.

```
$("#dnn_htmlPan1.htmlPan").find(":header").click(function () {
    $("#dnn_htmlPan1").find("p").slideToggle("slow");
});
$("#dnn_htmlPan2.htmlPan").find(":header").click(function () {
    $("#dnn_htmlPan2").find("p").slideToggle("slow");
});
$("#dnn_htmlPan3.htmlPan").find(":header").click(function () {
    $("#dnn_htmlPan3").find("p").slideToggle("slow");
});
$("#dnn_htmlPan4.htmlPan").find(":header").click(function () {
    $("#dnn_htmlPan4").find("p").slideToggle("slow");

});
$("#dnn_htmlPan5.htmlPan").find(":header").click(function () {
    $("#dnn_htmlPan5").find("p").slideToggle("slow");

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without knowing what your elements are or the html around them, i would say just combine the id's into one selector and use $(this).find in the click function. Example:

```
$("#id1, #id2, #id3").find(':header').click(function(){
 $(this).find('p').slideToggle('slow')l
});
```